# Redirect user to custom page when s/he is not authorized when using ADFS and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, adfs

My ADFS configuration excludes all users that don't belong to a set of groups.

There are situations where a user logs in using ADFS to a web app (web app B) and is given a set of claims that don't contain any groups accepted in web app A.

The user then goes to web app A, is redirect to ADFS, the user already has a cookie for ADFS so he isn't asked for a new user/password combination, and he's immediately redirect with the same claims (web app B's claims) to web app A.

This will trigger a 401 in web app A, which is correct.

How can we redirect the user to a page that explains what just happened (with a "login with a different account" button)?

For reference the web.config configuration that excludes all users that don't belong to a set of groups is:

```
<authentication mode="None" />
<authorization>
  <allow roles="GroupA,GroupB,GroupC,GroupD"/>
  <deny users="*" />
</authorization>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone has to deal with this, this is how I got to show a custom unauthorized page.

Create a custom unauthorized page, maybe put a logout button there, I put mine in ErrorController and named the action Unauthorized.

First "white-list" the custom "you are not authorized" page in web.config

```
<location path="Error/Unauthorized">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow Users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

Note: if you use resharper it will highlight that the path "Error/Unauthorized" does not exist. Just ignore it, it's because if you were using webforms that path would map to a physical file, but with MVC that isn't the case.

If you want to allow the user to log out so that s/he can log in with another account, you should also setup a logout url as not having any requirements in terms of groups:

```
<location path="Home/Logout">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <allow Users="*"/>
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

You should now handle the requests that reach the end of the "pipeline" with a 401 Unauthorized where the user is Authenticated, and redirect them to the custom unauthorized page:

In global.asax register an event on EndRequest and do the checks, change the response to 302 Found (temporary redirect) to the custom unauthorized page:

ctor:

```
protected MvcApplication(){
  EndRequest+=(s, e) => 
  {
    if (Response.StatusCode == 401 && User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
      Response.StatusCode = 302;
      Response.Headers.Add("Location", VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Error/Unauthorized"));
    }
  }
}
```

`System.Web.VirtualPathUtility` is very useful here because it expands the ~ and generates the full url

The location header is just the name of the header that is used by the browser when it gets a 302 response. It will then perform a request to the url in that is the header value.

I was convinced that the `WSFederationAuthenticationModule` would cater for this scenario with a setting in web.config, but I really couldn't find it.

For reference here's the all the settings in web.config put together:

```
<configuration>
 ...
    <location path="Error/Unauthorized">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow Users="*"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location>
    <location path="Home/Logout">
        <system.web>
            <authorization>
                <allow Users="*"/>
            </authorization>
        </system.web>
    </location> 
    <system.web>
        <authentication mode="None" />
        <authorization>
           <allow roles="GroupA,GroupB,GroupC,GroupD"/>
           <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
        ...
    </system.web>
    <system.identityModel>
    ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify the page to redirect to for a 401:

```
<customErrors mode="On">
    <error code="401" path="401.cshtml" />
</customErrors>
```

Do your authorisation stuff in the 401 page.

Comment: Unfortunately that does not work. The actual error code that is used in this situation is 401.2 and it never seems to match customErrors's 401. Also I believe it's `redirect` instead of `path` and you can't redirect directly to a `.cshtml` page (there's no http handler for that). A controller action would do (redirect="Error/Unauthorized"), but again, tried that and the redirect never happens.